# Three Column Design, dynamic width left + right side and static witdh in the middle

Tags: css, html, width

I want to have a dynamic three column design, where the center has a static width(for instance 250px) and the left + right columns dynamic width's. So every user can use it even they don't have the same browser width. It's also important that the 2nd div is really in the center of the window.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="navigation_left">left</div>
    <div id="navigation_center">center</div>
    <div id="navigation_right">right</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#header {
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
}
#navigation_left {
    float: left;
    background: rgba(128, 255, 128, 1);
    width: 80px; /* should be dynamic */
    height: inherit;
}
#navigation_right {
    float: right;
    background: rgba(255, 128, 128, 1);
    width: 80px; /* should be dynamic */
    height: inherit;
}
#navigation_center {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 250px;
    height: inherit;
    background: rgba(128, 128, 255, 1);
}
```

The problem so far is sometimes the left + right div's are too small or too big, because I said them hardcoded to 80px. Is there a way to fix this problem?

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yVtsq/)

Comment: Use percentages and set a min width and max-width?

Comment: The center div should be 250px for sure and not in percentage. In real it would be 1000px but for the demo / question 250px is easier.

Comment: for sure the middle can be 250px, but on the outer divs you can set them to percentages surely? You'd be best setting a width in a parent div to make it easier, and if it's to fit the users screen, use media queries/javascript to get the window dimensions

Comment: That's still not really working, because I don't know the percentage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

First, move your #navigation_center below #navigation_right so it doesn't get overlapped by the latest.

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="navigation_left">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
    <div id="navigation_right">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </div>
    <div id="navigation_center">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptates consectetur veritatis fugit aspernatur quo repellendus corrupti perferendis inventore dignissimos sapiente ea ullam libero consequatur voluptatibus quam sint deleniti dolor illo molestias numquam ex iusto incidunt quidem.
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, this CSS:

```
#header {
    height: 200px;
    background: #f80;
    position: relative; /* we will absolute-position children columns */

    /* text-align: center;  /* Remove this*/
}
#navigation_left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: #0f0;
    height: 100%;

    /* Here comes the magic: */
    width: 50%;
    padding-right: 125px; /* substract 250/2 from the content area */

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* So that padding is substracted instead of added */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#navigation_right {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0; /* change left to right */
   top: 0;
   background: #00f;
   height: 100%;

   width: 50%;
   padding-left: 125px; /* change left to right */

   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* So that padding is substracted instead of added */
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#navigation_center {
    position: relative;

    /* center the element */
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;

    width: 250px;
    background: rgba(128, 128, 255, 1);

    height: 100%;
}
```

Live example
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hzrdG

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with CSS3. Set the width of your left & right columns. Let's say 50px each. then set the width of the middle column with calculations.

```
-webkit-calc(width: 100% - 100px) /* -50px per column equals 100px */
-moz-calc(width: 100% - 100px) /* -50px per column equals 100px */
-o-calc(width: 100% - 100px) /* -50px per column equals 100px */
-ms-calc(width: 100% - 100px) /* -50px per column equals 100px */
calc(width: 100% - 100px) /* -50px per column equals 100px */
```

However, this doesn't work in older browsers, but you can get close by setting a width percentage for each column as a fallback.

Comment: +1 for calc (I didnt know that one). I like the other solution since it should support ie6 etc.