# How to have three elements fill a div, where center element has dynamic width?

Tags: html, css, width

I'm trying to design an interface for a user to insert either a prefix or a suffix of a word. Ideally, the word (randomly chosen) will be displayed in the center of the wrapper and then the text boxes on either side will stretch to the edges of the wrapper. Here's the setup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">{{text input}}</div>
  <div class="center">{{dynamic content}}</div>
  <div class="right">{{text input}}</div>
</div>
```

Which would look something like the following (where underscores are text input fields, lowercase are possible inputs):

```
|________CONDITION________| => |____pre_CONDITION________| or |________CONDITION_al_____|
|__________ALLOW__________| => |______dis_ALLOW__________| or |__________ALLOW_ance_____|
|___________RUN___________| => |______over_RUN___________| or |___________RUN_ner_______|
```

I have seen problems similar to this before, but I have not been able to find a solution to this one. The center div does not have a static width, so I cannot [determine the widths manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775612/three-column-design-dynamic-width-left-right-side-and-static-witdh-in-the-mid). I need the left and right divs to contain actual content (not just styling) so I can't really [change the HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474212/container-fix-width-center-div-dynamic-width-want-left-right-divs-to-fill-out). I am looking for a solution which allows the center div to have any width and forces the left and right divs to fill the remaining horizontal space.

Is there any way to do this with CSS? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flex`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.left, .right {
  flex: 1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid
}
.center {
  flex: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">text input</div>
  <div class="center">dynamic content</div>
  <div class="right">text input</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">text input</div>
  <div class="center">dynamic content, longer</div>
  <div class="right">text input</div>
</div>
```

Or `display: table`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table-row;
}
.left, .right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid
}
.center {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">text input</div>
  <div class="center">dynamic content</div>
  <div class="right">text input</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">text input</div>
  <div class="center">dynamic content, longer</div>
  <div class="right">text input</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much. The only thing I had to change was width: 50% to 100% for `.left` and `.right` to fill their table-cells.